# DBMS - Music genre normalization in a database

Tags: database, rdbms, database-normalization

So I am trying to wrap my head around the whole "normalization" thing. To understand it better, I have come up with a this case of storing songs

Suppose I have the following db:

**Album Table:**

```
album_name| genre           
   album_1| genre_1, genre_2
   album_2| genre_1
   album_3| genre_2
```

To normalize, I thought of the following approach

**Album Table:**

```
album_name| genre_id          
   album_1|        3
   album_2|        1
   album_3|        2
```

**Genre Table:**

```
genre_id| genre_1| genre_2
       0|   false|   false
       1|    true|   false
       2|   false|    true
       3|    true|    true
```

Thus, if a new genre pops up, all I need to do is create a new column in genre table and the new corresponding `genre_id` can be assigned. Well, that will require filling up of all possible combinations, but that will only happen once for every new genre introduced.

> Also, what I thought of, will that be considered "normalizing"? From the examples I have seen around, I haven't seen creation of tables with columns that were originally data.

Comment: Also, if you can't already tell, I am in the "learners" stage. So any links ( in the comments)  to **good** resources out there to understand normalization, will be helpful.

Comment: I suggest also visiting the sister site: https://dba.stackexchange.com  In particular, see [this similar Question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/202769/19079).

Comment: Hi. Dozens of information modeling & relational datbase textbook pdfs are free online. Read & follow one. You are just asking us to write one. Plus nevertheless these questions are SO faqs. If you don't know what "normalization" is you should be finding out, not asking in a SO question. And you need to learn the basics of design.

Comment: @philipxy I am more of a learning by doing kind of guy. And sometimes even a single Q/A on SO is way more helpful than an entire chapter on the topic. And about your last line, in case you missed, I am learning the basics, thus the question. Anyway thanks for caring to reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical way of doing this would be to use *three* tables:

```
Album    | 
album_id | album_name  (and maybe other columns)
1        | Rumours
2        | Thriller
3        | To the Moon and Back

Genre
genre_id | genre_name  (also maybe other columns)
1        | rock
2        | pop
3        | alternative

AlbumGenre
album_id | genre_id
1        | 1
1        | 2
2        | 2
3        | 2
3        | 3
```

Normalization is all about avoiding the storage of repetitive data.  If you scrutinize this design, you will see that information about albums and genres is stored only once, in each respective table.  Then, the `AlbumGenre` table stores the relationships between albums and the various genres.  This table is usually called a "bridge" table, because it links albums to their genres.

The problem with your proposed `Genre` table is that it repeats information about relationships even if those relationships don't exist.  Furthermore, this approach won't scale well at all if you need to add more genres to the database.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But I'd like to clarify two points: "it repeats information about relationships even if those relationships don't exist" - which information are you referring to? the genre combinations? Also, is not repeating `album_id` in `album_genre` repetitive?

Comment: You are storing state for all genres, for each album, regardless of whether that album actually has those genres.  In addition, your truth table will grow by a factor of 2 for each new genre added.  This won't scale at all.

Comment: Indeed, for only 100 genres it it becomes massive. I missed that point. So in conclusion, repetition in the bridge is ok as long as the the fields are directly interdependent?

Comment: Yes.  The primary key in the bridge table is the combination of album and genre, and this should never be repeated.

Answer (score 1):

The relationship you defined is a many to many relationship. In general you don't want to be adding new columns when you add new data. So we need to look at another solution.

First we define tables for the Albums and Genres:

**Album Table:**

```
album_id | album_name           
       1 |    album_1
       2 |    album_2
       3 |    album_3
```

**Genre Table:**

```
genre_id | genre_name
       1 |    genre_1
       2 |    genre_2
       3 |    genre_3
```

Now we need to link those two. We use a junction table to do that. Each instance of a genre belonging to an album will have a row in this table. So albums could be listed in this table multiple times.

**Album Genres Junction Table:**

```
album_genre_junction_id | album_id | genre_id
                      1          1          1
                      2          1          2
                      3          2          1
                      4          3          2
```